# How to get Timestamp of the current Date and time in Rust

Tags: datetime, rust

I simply want to retrieve the current Time and Date and store it in a variable.
For this, I tried to use the `chrono::DateTime`.

In the documentation I found this:

```rust
use chrono::{DateTime, TimeZone, NaiveDateTime, Utc};

let dt = DateTime::<Utc>::from_utc(NaiveDate::from_ymd(2016, 7, 8).and_hms(9, 10, 11), Utc);
```

This lets me store a specific Date and Time but I couldn't figure out how to retrieve the actual current date and time and put it in my DateTime-Variable.

Comment: See also [`Instant::now`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.Instant.html#method.now) and [`SystemTime::now`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/time/struct.SystemTime.html#method.now)

Comment: "I simply want to retrieve" There is no such thing as "simply" in time and date calculation, or in all of programming for that matter.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```rust
use chrono;

fn main() {
    // returns DateTime<Local>
    println!("{:?}", chrono::offset::Local::now());

    // returns DateTime<Utc>
    // NOTE: Available on crate feature *clock* only.
    println!("{:?}", chrono::offset::Utc::now());
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=30c976a8713eaf36a4cd1909878a04fd)

---

Sources:

[chrono::offset::Local#method.now](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Local.html#method.now)

[chrono::offset::Utc#method.now](https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/offset/struct.Utc.html#method.now)

Comment: This is no longer working @edwardw

Comment: @0x12 except it still works? The latest version (0.4.23) of `chrono` does say the `Utc::now` is now behind a crate feature, but the code still compiles as is.

Comment: working ! Cheers

Comment: it works with rustc 1.66.1

Answer (score 18):

To answer the question in the title of how to get the current timestamp:

```rust
use chrono::Utc;

let dt = Utc::now();
let timestamp: i64 = dt.timestamp();

println!("Current timestamp is {}", timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use chrono for time stampping, add chrono in Cargo.toml file.
ex)
[dependencies]
chrono = "=0.4.37"